# jQuery hover not working as needed

Tags: jquery

I would like to get the arrows for the carousel appearing and disappearing when hovering on the slideshow. I have tried this but not much success:

```
$("#slideshow").hover(function(){$('.control').fadeOut(500);$('control').fadeIn(500);});
```

[full code here](http://jsfiddle.net/asWeb/EsGLn/4/)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong syntax for `hover()` for what you want to do. The hover() method takes two callbacks, one for the onmouseover event (hover), and one for the onmouseout event (off hover).

```
$('#slideshow').hover(
    function(){
        $('.control').fadeIn(500);
    },
    function(){
        $('.control').fadeOut(500);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi this one works fine, however I realised that by fading in both arrows it gives the option to slide the first image to the left meaning that it goes to a blank space. I guess I will have to play around with conditional statements to check if it is the last slide. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you're missing a dot before `.control` in the `.fadeIn(...)` call.

Also, you can simplify the code a bit, and get rid of the error.

```
$('.control')
    .fadeOut(500)
    .fadeIn(500);
```

Of course, this would just "blink" the controls - see @AndrewR's answer for the right functionality =)

Answer (score 1):

Just chain your `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` calls together. You don't want to be selecting the same element set twice for no good reason.

```
$('.control').fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
```

Comment: It doesn't quite work as expected it seems to fades out and in quickly http://jsfiddle.net/asWeb/EsGLn/9/

Comment: I think I know what you've been really wanting to get this code doing. Check out @AndrewR's answer above. :D